# 8 puzzle building graph

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to solve the 8 puzzle problem. I need to create a graph with all the boards and then run DFS or BFS to find a path. I am facing a problem with constructing the graph. I know that I need a for loop that will run 9! times, but the problem is I keep getting an array out of bounds exception when I run the code. This is the code I have for building the graph.

B is a 2d array with 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Please show how `B` is initialised

Comment: B is a 2d array with 3 rows and 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here

```
if(B[i][j+1]==0){
```

will causes an OOB exception when `j == B[i].length - 1`

There are other places as well where you add one to the index of the array.

Comment: I want to upvote this several times. I too saw it as soon as i looked and i though, if only i could make sure everyone got this.

Comment: Thanks for you comment Ben